# Как найти индекс списка в списке, который содержит точку, ближайшую (по расстоянию) к точке "n"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, список, python-3.5

Ответ должен быть 1, т.к. ближайшее значение в 1 по индексу списке.

```py
point = [
    [(540, 420), (620, 300), (370, 140), (250, 390)],
    [(60, 30), (550, 310), (50, 520)],
    [(200, 500), (370, 390), (170, 200)]
]

n = (20, 15)

items = []
for idx, area in enumerate(point):
            for x, y in area:
                items.append((idx, x, y))
```

Comment: Ваши варианты решения приложите.

Comment: имеется ввиду минимальное расстояние до точки `n` ?

Comment: @MaxU Да, именно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def squared_dist(p1, p2):
     return ((p1[0] - p2[0])**2 + (p1[1] - p2[1])**2)

def dist(p1, p2):
     return squared_dist(p1, p2) ** .5

items = [(i,x,y) for i,r in enumerate(point) for x,y in r]


nearest_point = min(items, key=lambda x: squared_dist(n, x[1:]))
```

результат:

```
In [95]: nearest_point
Out[95]: (1, 60, 30)

In [96]: nearest_point[0]
Out[96]: 1
```

---

`items` - список точек (кортежей), где первый элемент представляет собой индекс строки / списка, содержащего данную точку, а остальные два - координаты `x` и `y`:

```
In [17]: items
Out[17]:
[(0, 540, 420),
 (0, 620, 300),
 (0, 370, 140),
 (0, 250, 390),
 (1, 60, 30),
 (1, 550, 310),
 (1, 50, 520),
 (2, 200, 500),
 (2, 370, 390),
 (2, 170, 200)]
```

Comment: можете [92] строку расшифровать?

Comment: @Иван, дополнил ответ ...

Comment: Для целей сравнения корень извлекать не нужно (излишне).

Comment: @MBo, абсолютно согласен! Но данную функцию можно использовать не только для сравнения ;)

Comment: @MaxU Да, но для сравнения разумно `squared_dist` сделать ;)

Comment: @MBo, ok, убедили :)